# Asus N56JR laptop, can't change screen Brightness using Function Keys

Tags: nvidia, shortcut-keys, laptop, brightness

I have an Asus N56JR laptop with Nvidia GeForce GTX 760M graphics card, running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. 
When I check what graphics I use for brightness it says "Intel".

- I have tried using commands to change the brightness (no luck)
- I have tried editing the config files (none here either)
- I have tried installing Brightness Indicator and using custom shortcuts to change the brightness (nada).

I have not been able to change the brightness at all, no matter how I try. I know the laptop can change the brightness and it is not a hardware issue because I have a dual-boot with Windows-8 and on Windows the brightness control works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I did a fake solution with the xbackligth tool. I associated a combo like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> with the `xbackligth -10` command against <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> with the `xbackligth +10`

May help

Comment: I have tried this already and it does not affect the brightness at all.

Comment: Did you try the commands in a terminal first?

Answer (score 0):

add this kernel parameter:
acpi_backlight=vendor

```
    menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os         $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-bafb083d-0d91-475d-8c72-4ee4b6069050' {
            recordfail
            load_video
            gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
            insmod gzio
            insmod part_msdos
            insmod ext2
           set root='hd0,msdos1'
           if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  bafb083d-0d91-475d-8c72-4ee4b6069050
            else
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root bafb083d-0d91-475d-8c72-4ee4b6069050
           fi
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=bafb083d-0d91-475d-8c72-4ee4b6069050 ro acpi_backlight=vendor quiet splash $vt_handoff
            initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
   }
```

improtant:
editing grub.cfg is not the official way and after running grup-update the changes would be removed. but this is a easy way to see if this solution works.

Comment: Could you explain a little more how to do that? Click [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/543925/edit) below your answer and add the information.